# Avoid duplicates NSFetchRequest Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, core-data

There's the problem. I need to populate a UITableview with a list of authors fetched from a Core Data entity (scientific papers). However, as some authors wrote more than one scientific paper, they will appear multiple times in the UItableView. Is there a way to limit the duplicates in NSFetchRequest?

Comment: Show your model, sample data and your current fetch code

Comment: I need a query like SELECT DISTINCT Autor FROM Scientificpapers, and then populate a UITableview with the resulting Array. What seem obvious to me in SQLite is specially cryptic in Core Data.

Comment: why? you should have a list of people who are connected to a list of documents, so both lists are unique and the relationships describe the other aspect of the data set...

Comment: I wish it was that straightforward. Unfortunately, my model imports data from a CSV file created with Excel and located in AWS. The CSV file is updated frequently and the App must translate it to comply with the Core Data protocol.

Comment: so you can remove duplicates during that processing - sanitise the incoming data and keep the app data clean

Comment: Thanks for your interest! Imagine there are 5 records in my DB.

Comment: The Number of the Beast    Iron Maiden

Comment: Piece of Mind    iron Maiden        Killers Iron Maiden          British Steel  Judas Priest        The Wall    Pink Floyd.    In my table "artists" I want to have Just Iron Maiden, Judas Priest and Pink Floyd. I cannot remove duplicates during the income processing, because if I want to have de "records" I need to fetch all five of them.

Comment: you separate them, so you have 3 artists, and 5 records, and each record is linked to an artist (the relationship)

Comment: You're right. That's probably the way. I'll try to figure out how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Did it another way:

Comment: authors = Array(Set(temporaryAuthorsArray)), and then used authors as the data for the UITableView